# Material-UI Autocomplete update state onChange and custom values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am experimenting with Material-UI Autocomplete implementation. I've got it to work but I was wondering if it is possible the state to be updated whenever the value of the Autocomplete box is updated so, if used in a form, I have the value for the post request.

Also I was wondering if it is possible to have a custom value in the Autocomplete in case the user hasn't found any value he likes.

Here is my implementation: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-flz9r

So far I have tried adding onChange on a few different places but without success.

Any help is appreciated